# Bootstrap and map design for elements on map

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap and map API. Map Api uses the %100 height. I want to show created elements with bootstrap on the map. [`Jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/barteloma/JN7RZ/7/) is here.

I want to show like this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You must wrap your **mapDiv** with another div, make the 'wrapper' and the 'panel' **absolute**
so your panel can fly above your map, and you can set the location of your panel with top, left, bottom, or right.

**the wrapperMap:**

```
<div class="wrapperMap">
    <div id="mapDiv"></div>
</div>

<div id="fly" class="panel panel-warning">
     <div class="panel-heading">
         <h3 class="panel-title">Layers Not Found</h3>
     </div>
     <div class="panel-body">Sorry, I could not list layers!</div>
</div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
#fly {
    position: absolute;
    clear: none;
    left: 20%;
}
.wrapperMap {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    clear: none;
}
```

look at this [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JN7RZ/11/)